# Insert overwrite in hive doesn't work properly

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm creating external tables in hive and then user `insert overwrite directory ...` to add the files. However the second time that I run my query I expect the old files to get deleted and new files replace them (because I have the overwrite option). However that is not the case and new files gets added to the directory without removing the old files which causes inconsistency in the data. What is going wrong here?

Comment: is your hive table partitioned?

Comment: no it is not partitioned, it is a simple table

Answer (score 1):

I was going to submit a bug but this is existing issue : [HIVE-13997](https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/HIVE-13997) -- apply the patch if you wish to use `overwrite directory` for expected results.

From Test what I have found is:

`overwrite directory` and `overwrite table` works differently: you should use `overwrite table` if you wish to overwrite the entire directory.

created this table for test: `create external table t2 (a1 int,a2 string) LOCATION '/user/cloudera/t2';`

***`overwrite directory:`***

The directory is, as you would expect, OVERWRITten; in other words, if the specified path exists, it is clobbered and replaced with the output.

`hive> insert overwrite directory '/user/cloudera/t2' select * from sqoop_import.departments;`

so if above statement is going to write data at location `/user/cloudera/t2/000000_0` then only this location is overwritten.

```
#~~~~ BEFORE ~~~~
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hadoop fs -ls /user/cloudera/t2/*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 cloudera cloudera         60 2016-07-25 17:42 /user/cloudera/t2/000000_0
-rwxr-xr-x   1 cloudera cloudera          0 2016-07-25 15:48 /user/cloudera/t2/_SUCCESS
-rwxr-xr-x   1 cloudera cloudera         88 2016-07-25 15:48 /user/cloudera/t2/part-m-00000
-rwxr-xr-x   1 cloudera cloudera         60 2016-07-25 15:48 /user/cloudera/t2/part-m-00001

#~~~~ AFTER: Note the timestamp ~~~~
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hadoop fs -ls /user/cloudera/t2/*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 cloudera cloudera         60 2016-07-25 18:01 /user/cloudera/t2/000000_0
-rwxr-xr-x   1 cloudera cloudera          0 2016-07-25 15:48 /user/cloudera/t2/_SUCCESS
-rwxr-xr-x   1 cloudera cloudera         88 2016-07-25 15:48 /user/cloudera/t2/part-m-00000
-rwxr-xr-x   1 cloudera cloudera         60 2016-07-25 15:48 /user/cloudera/t2/part-m-00001
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

***`overwrite table:`***

The contents of the chosen table or partition are replaced with the output of corresponding select statement.

`hive> insert overwrite table t2 select * from sqoop_import.departments;`

Now entire dir is overwritten:

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hadoop fs -ls /user/cloudera/t2/*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 cloudera cloudera         60 2016-07-25 18:03 /user/cloudera/t2/000000_0
-rwxr-xr-x   1 cloudera cloudera          0 2016-07-25 15:48 /user/cloudera/t2/_SUCCESS
```

so in conclusion, overwrite directory only overwrite direct path of generated file not the directory. [see Writing-data-into-the-file-system-from-queries](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Writingdataintothefilesystemfromqueries)